# A regular expression to prevent a duplicate token

Tags: c#, regex

Can you please help me to find a expression to accept these :

```
C1D3
A1Z5R7
H2L7V5X3
```

but does not accept these :

```
A1B2A2 //Because the A repeated 2 times
C4F5F3
C2C1
B1B2F6
```

I am tring to create a expression to use it in C#.Net

Comment: To solve this problem, you need to step through each character of the token; keep track of what you have seen. If you encounter something you have seen before (its a duplicate), stop and reject that token.

Comment: Does the pattern fail if there is the same digits ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a bunch of Capital Letter/Number pairs...

```
/^(([A-Z])(?!.*\2)[0-9])+$/g
```

### Breakdown...

```
/^          # Start regex, and pattern match
(           # Start group 1
([A-Z])     # Capture any character from A-Z into group 2
(?!.*\2)    # Do negative lookahead `(?!...)` to ensure there is no repeat of the captured group 2 (`\2`), after zero or more of anything (`.*`)
[0-9]       # Capture a digit
)+          # End group 1
$/g         # End regex, and pattern match, with global flag set
```

### Alternatively, for all tokens to avoid repetition equally...

```
/^(([A-Z0-9])(?!.*\2))+$/g
```

Comment: This fails with `C1D1`

Comment: I don't think it is clear in the question, whether numerics are considered as tokens equally with letters - which is why I supplied the alternative regex to cover no repeating of numbers too.

Answer (score 3):

In this sort of problem back-references are you're friend.

so `(.).*\1` will match a character followed by anything followed by whatever the first capture group matched

Answer (score 0):

```
string pattern=@"\w+"; 
var uniqueCharWords=Regex.Matches(input,pattern)
                         .Cast<Match>()
                         .Where(x=>x.Value.Distinct()==x.Value.Length);
```

---

If you are looking for a perfect regex,this is it

```
string pattern=@"\b(?!\w*(\w)\w*\1\w*)\w+\b";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(str);
string line;
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   if (line.Distinct().Count() != line.Length)
       return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this negative lookahead based rgex to avoid matching duplicate containing strings:

```
/^(?:(.)(?!.*?\1))+$/

/^(?:(.)(?!.*?\1))+$/.test('A1B2D3');  // true
/^(?:(.)(?!.*?\1))+$/.test('A1B2A3');  // false
```

Comment: This fails with `C1D1`

Comment: But C1D1 should fail right?

Comment: I believe that it's only for same letters. (but I am not sure, I will ask.)

Comment: in that case dot can be replaced by `[a-z]`